# Submitting queries to fetch Json data with updated date string

Tags: json, swift, date, swift4.2

When we are fetching Json data from web, we have to include date in string format. However it works only when I am submitting raw string values. When I create a string instance with the same value (using Date()) , the request is not working out. I tried with this code:

```
var formattedDate = { ()-> String in let dateString = String(describing: Date()) 
let formatter = DateFormatter() formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" formatter.dateStyle = .short return dateString }() 

let dateString = "\"\(formattedDate.dropLast(15))"+"\"" 
//then instead of :
 let query: [String : String] = ["api_key" : "DEMO_KEY", "date" : "2012-02-12"] 
//this: 
let query: [String : String] = ["api_key" : "DEMO_KEY", "date" : dateString]
```

Didn't work! Formatting produces the same exact string value though! Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create `DateFormatter` and set its `dateFormat` to your needed format (`"yyyy-MM-dd"`). Then you can just get formatted string from some date using `string(from:)` on formatter

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())
let query: [String : String] = ["api_key" : "DEMO_KEY", "date" : dateString]
```

... note that I removed <strike>`formatter.dateStyle = .short`</strike> since this gives you format which you probably don't need (e.g. 2/12/19) and I also removed double quotes since in your example query I can’t see any (these quotes are here just for `String`)

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is much simpler, but still doesn't work. I only get data, when I add "2019-02-11" manually. But that sucks, since I would like to update my app's view daily.

Comment: @GergelyKovacs are you sure that you didn’t add double quotes? That you used exactly what I wrote?

Comment: @GergelyKovacs so do you have just `let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())`?

Comment: Wow, yes, now it works! Thanks! Yes first I didn't remove the +"\""